# WebView appears white while progressbar loads

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

I have a `ProgressBar` that is shown when a `WebView` is loading. I'd like the `ProgressBar` to be shown with a small size, while the background is black. Then I can dismiss the progress bar when the WebView has loaded.

The problem I have is that the `WebView` is white while it is loading. Is there any way to make it black? If I set the background color of the `WebView` to black, for a brief second, it is still white, and makes the loading quite ugly.

The layout of the Activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively, should I use some sort of an image that looks similar to the Android progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your XML:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000" />
```

And do this in code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_fragment, container, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(
            R.id.webview);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Setting it in code worked for me. I've updated the answer, can you try that?

Comment: If I try this, the length of time the white screen appears is shorter, albeit still there

Comment: My webview turns black immediately, as I update the color before the end of `onCreateView`. Can you post the content of your onCreateView method? Is the webview white at first? Add some breakpoints: When does the webview change from white to black?

Comment: That's perfect, Rogier. it works. I was setting the background color after some delay in onCreate(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your relativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#000000">
```

Comment: You can do one thing, first set the visibility of webView to invisible, till the progress bar loads, when the progress bar is getting dismissed at that time setVisibility to visible